# Moving from support vector machine to neural network (Back propagation)

Tags: neural-network, svm, encog

I'm working with text recognition and currently I'm using support vector machine method. I would like to try with neural network also. I read a few documents about how neural network works, but the theory is quite heavy and I don't know exactly how will it apply to my case. So it would be good if someone can help me to make it clear, especially with the neural network's architecture.

- Currently, in SVM, I have 200 features (divided into 4 main
  categories), which is used to recognize the text. If I move to neural
  network, With 200 features, does it mean that I will have 200 neutrons in the input layer?
- With 200 features, how will that result in the architecture of the neural
  network (in term of numbers layers (hidden layer) and
  neutrons)?
- In SVM, I have one class classification (basically, true and false) and multi-class classification (labels), how this difference will apply to the output layer of the neural networks?

And I also have a few general questions :

- What will help to decide the number of hidden layers and the number of neutrons inside each hidden layer?
- Does the number of hidden layer relate to the accuracy ?

I'm new to neural network so it would be great if you can explain to me in an understable way. :) 

 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1 - it will be 200 input neurons, where each neuron is fed a binary number, or a float (preferably normalized in the range -1 to 1).

Point 2/4 - The majority of problems are solved with a single hidden layer. Certainly if you are starting out with neural networks you should stick to one hidden layer. I would also suggest starting with less than 200 input neurons, try 5 or 10. Multiple hidden layers are used in complex problems, for example, where the first hidden layer learns macro features like dog, cat, horse and the next hidden layer learns finer features like eyes, nose, ears etc.

There is no definite procedure for deciding the number of hidden neurons. The more complex a problem, in theory the more hidden neurons it needs. If you have 10 input neurons, start with say 20 hidden neurons. If it doesn't work, something is likely wrong elsewhere. If it does work, you can reduce the number of hidden neurons until it fails.
You can also start low and work up.

Point 3 - for true and false classification, use a single output neuron, and train it with 0 or 1. For n classes, use 1 of n encoding.

Point 5 - no. The accuracy is measured by how well the network can generalize - ie., how it performs on data its never seen before. In general, more training data = more accurate.

Comment: Hi, so for examples, if I have 200 features (02 categories, each category contains 100 features) and I want to use 2 hidden layers. So the input layer will have 200 neutrons, then as your suggestion, each hidden layer should start with 200 or 400 neutrons ? Thank you